# which is the best approach to replace content in a table from another table where they have duplicates using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, say, table_1 and table_2, they have the same columns, for example. they both have col1, col2, ..., col100.

Now, I want to replace all the content in table_1 with table_2. Note that we want to keep table_1 as it is queried by an external user.

which is the best practice, replace, drop, update, or append? and how to implement it using MySQL?

Comment: Drop table1 rename table2? Really there is no best practice it's up to you and your business to decide an approach which works for you. AND test it before implementing in production.

Comment: Whatever you decide make sure you don't upset FKs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSERT INTO SELECT`

**Step:1** - `TRUNCATE TABLE table_name`

**Step:2**

```
INSERT INTO table_name(column names)
SELECT 
   column names 
FROM 
   another_table
WHERE
   condition;
```

Comment: Truncate would be quicker than delete.